# WPF mvvm wizard

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am implementing WPF MVVM Wizard and I am wondering about the right approach of performing  a `DoOperation` when a new Wizard’s Page (UserControl)  is loaded.

The `DoOperation` is implemented on the `MyWizard.ViewModal` class while the `UserControl`  Load is happening at the `MyWizard.View` namespaces.

How can I connect between the `UserControl`  loaded event to the `DoOperation` api?

I tried the following:

```
<xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=RunOperation}"/
    </i:EventTrigger> 
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

`RunOperation` calls `DoOperation`.

it doesn’t work, `RunOperation` is not being called.

This is the right approach or there is a better way to perform an operation at the  `MyWizard.ViewModal` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach should work. Have you checked your output console for binding errors? Is `RunOperation` a command? Is the DataContext of the UserControl already set, when the `Loaded` event is raised? Have you implemented the triggers like this in your UC?

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="..."
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                  
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=RunOperation}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>

    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```